# Definition of MLE and PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, maximum-likelihood

Sorry for another question on MLE and PDF.

I understand ( or at least I think I do) how MLE is used to find the parameters for a given distribution such as a Gaussian one but I have a question based on the definition of MLE and PDF.

Let’s supposed that I’m collecting data for an experiment which is known to be a continuous Gaussian and I collect the following numbers : 10,10,11,12,13,12

I know how to use these numbers to calculate the mean and variance for the distribution.

Per my understanding, a more formal definition would be : I’m finding the mean and variance that maximize likelihood of the joint probability  P(10) x P(10) x P (11) x P(12)..

Since my variable is continuous, the probability of a given number is always zero by definition. So, P(10)=0, P(11) = 0, etc.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you say "I know how to use these numbers to calculate the mean and variance for the distribution" you really mean "I know how to use these numbers to estimate the mean and variance for the distribution". MLE is one way to do this estimation, but not the only one. As Robert Israel said, if you're doing MLE on a continuous model, you maximize a probability density rather than a probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting exactly those values from a continuous distribution would indeed be $0$.  The likelihood you are maximizing is not a probability, but a [probability density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).